# converting listlayers into a list using arcpy . (arcpro python3)

Tags: python, list, arcgis, arcpy

How do I convert the lyr variable into a list? The variable type is listed as class 'arcpy._mp.Layer'. Should I convert this to string then insert into list?

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("./test.aprx")
for m in aprx.listMaps():
    for lyr in m.listLayers():
        print (lyr)

output
layer1
layer2
layer3

desired output
['layer1', 'layer2', 'layer3']
```

ex: 2

```
for m in aprx.listMaps():
    for lyr in m.listLayers():
        layer = [str(lyr)]
        print (layer)
output
['layer1']
['layer2']
['layer3']
```

This doesn't seem to get into a list either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m.listLayers()` already returns a list of Layer objects of type [`arcpy._mp.Layer`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layer-class.htm). You just need to build a list of layer names. Here's how you can do that:

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("./test.aprx")

map_layers = []  # list of lists where each sublist contains layer names for each map in project

for m in aprx.listMaps():
    lyr_names = []  # initialize an empty list and append layer names to it in every iteration
    for lyr in m.listLayers():
       lyr_names.append(lyr.name)
    map_layers.append(lyr_names)

print(map_layers)
```

So if your Project had 2 maps where each map had 3 layers each, the above snippet would print the result like this:

```
[['Map 1 Layer 1 Name', 'Map 1 Layer 2 Name', 'Map 1 Layer 3 Name'],
 ['Map 2 Layer 1 Name', 'Map 2 Layer 2 Name', 'Map 2 Layer 3 Name']]
```